# Custom Map ID Google Maps Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3, flutter-web

I am looking to implement a custom-styled Google Map instance in my Flutter (web) app. I have generated a custom-styled map in Google Cloud Platform and have its `id` but am unable to set the map style by `mapId` as this method is not defined in the dart API. Is there any workaround?

JS:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
  zoom: num,
  mapId: 'MAP_ID'
});
```

Dart:

```
  final mapOptions = MapOptions()
  ..zoom = num
  ..center = LatLng
  ..mapTypeControlOptions = MapTypeControlOptions
  ..mapId = 'MAP_ID'; 
  final map = GMap(Element, mapOptions);
```

Custom map types:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Package:

- I am using `google_maps: ^5.1.0` which can be found at https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps.

Comment: Seems like the feature is not yet implemented in google_maps: ^5.1.0